# What's wrong with "her first devotion was to dancing"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In Susan Sontag's review of *The Last of the Nuba*, [*Fascinating Fascism*](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/archives/1975/feb/06/fascinating-fascism/?pagination=false), by Leni Riefenstahl, one can read among other things:

> Could the publishers have let LR write the jacket copy herself? One
>   hesitates to entertain so unkind a thought, although “her first
>   devotion was to dancing” is a phrase few native speakers of English
>   would be capable of.

What is wrong with that sentence?

**Edit**: As was pointed out in a comment it depends on context. The book spans over Riefenstahl's life so we can assume that it means "her [very] first devotion [when she was a child]".

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, except possible the use of the past-tense *was*. If the author of the quote is accusing LR of writing the jacket copy, then presumably she was alive when she wrote it, whereas "*was*", when applied to humans and otherwise unqualified,  typically refers to the deceased. It's also possible LR's very first devotion, when she was a child or young woman, had been to dancing, but no longer is (maybe it's to writing now, or eradicating fascism), in which case "*was*", and the whole sentence, is just fine. Would depend on the full context of the sentence in the jacket copy.

Comment: Sounds dated. Google ngram puts its peak usage back around 1864: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=first+devotion&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfirst%20devotion%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @DanBron I believe it means "the very first devotion" - I adressed this in an edit to the question.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger That's a possible reason, but Sontag was born in 1933 and the review was written in 1975. She lived through times where the expression was relatively frequent compared to today, so why would she then think that no native would possibly write that?

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger: Your Google Books link shows a change over time for the two-word collocation, but [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+first+love%2Chis+first+devotion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20first%20love%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20first%20devotion%3B%2Cc0) more usefully backs up OP's cited sideswipe, by showing how uncommon **first devotion** it is by comparison with the standard **first love**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Replacing "devotion to" with "love of" feels wrong to me, since the verb *devote* is very different from the verb *love*. When I read the sentence I interpret it to say that dancing was the first thing she devoted herself to. But you are saying that love and devotion are really interchangeable and that the sentence means that dancing was the first thing she fell in love with?

Comment: @Pickett: Are you a native speaker? I'm not saying "devotion" is *wrong* in the sense of being somehow "invalid". But presumably we all accept that Susan Sontag has a good ear for current English. I completely agree with her assessment of the usage, as reflected here by T.E.D.'s answer (it's *understandable, but it looks odd*). Note that *my first love was dancing* normally means *at some point in the past (the time I'm talking about), dancing was what I cared about **most***. The *first = earliest* sense is only peripherally relevant to this commonplace expression.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The article was written in 1975, I am a non-native speaker born in 1990. I recognize that you and T.E.D. are right. I interpreted the sentence to mean "the first thing she devoted herself to [i.e. spent most of her time on] was dancing" but it turns out, as I now realize, that native speakers parse it "the first thing that she loved doing was dancing". I don't think I am alone among non-native speakers to have/have had this misconception since we tend to extrapolate between verbs and nouns, but it's been straightened out now (if my current understanding is correct).

Comment: It was my sense reading things that it was in fact the transition from verb to noun that tripped up the original author. The verb form can be used a bit more broadly. If I had to take a guess, I'd say the noun form came first and at some point it became "verbized". Trying to "nounize" it back when there's already a noun there is where non-native speakers are liable to get themselves into trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical (one might even say clichéd) phrasing of that would be "Her first love was dance".

The form written up there is longer, a bit tortured, almost certainly unfamiliar to readers, and arguably misuses the word "devotion".

"Devotion" as a direct object typically refers to a [prayer and/or worship](http://www.devotions.net/devotions/10october/3.htm) time (often in the morning). It certainly can and does sometime also mean something (non religious) a person does a lot, but still usually in a metaphorical sense comparing it to worship. Someone having a "first devotion" implies they have or had other ones, which is just weird since religions are generally exclusive things.

Its still understandable, but it looks odd, and I had to stop to parse it. I wouldn't have had to do that if they'd just used the normal English cliché.